# Repetitive squaring (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exponentiation

I implemented the [exponentiation by squaring algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) in Python

```
    (x,n)=(input(),input())

    def exp_itr(x,n):
        r=1
        while n!=0:
          if n%2==1:
            r=r*x
            n=n-1
          x=x*x
          n=n/2
    return r
```

And now, I need the recursive algorithm. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you try fixing your indentation? (You can click "edit" in the lower-left of your question to edit it)

Comment: correct the indent please ;)

Comment: fix it:),i fix the first problem(this is work now also if n id odd),now i just need the recursive algorithm

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `x**n` already does all that. In C.

Comment: The first section on the wikipedia page has a psuedo-code version of what you want - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method why not follow that example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Python version of the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method) mentioned in comments

```
def exp(x, n):
    if n < 0:
        return exp(1 / x, -n)
    elif n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return exp(x * x, n / 2)
    else:
        return x * exp(x * x, (n - 1) / 2)
```